# How to create right path in backup on osx in python?

Tags: python, macos, backup

I’ve tried to make some backup program from book “A Byte of Python” and ran into a error “No such file or directory”

I tried to change a lot of different paths to files and folders on my computer, also tried to change some syntax pieces(like /,,//,\, etc)
I’m new at coding and I get the impression that I’ve tried all I could
I’m coding on osx and here is the code from the book:

```
import os
import time

# 1. Файлы и каталоги, которые необходимо скопировать, собираются в список.
source = ['"C:\\My Documents"', 'C:\\Code']
# Заметьте, что для имён, содержащих пробелы, необходимо использовать
# двойные кавычки внутри строки.

# 2. Резервные копии должны храниться в основном каталоге резерва.
target_dir = 'E:\\Backup' # Подставьте тот путь, который вы будете использовать.

# 3. Файлы помещаются в zip-архив.
# 4. Именем для zip-архива служит текущая дата и время.
target = target_dir + os.sep + time.strftime('%Y%m%d%H%M%S') + '.zip'

# 5. Используем команду "zip" для помещения файлов в zip-архив
zip_command = "zip -qr {0} {1}".format(target, ' '.join(source))

# Запускаем создание резервной копии
if os.system(zip_command) == 0:
    print('Резервная копия успешно создана в', target)
else:
    print('Создание резервной копии НЕ УДАЛОСЬ')
```

Here is my 2 unsuccessful versions:

```
import os
import time

#1.  Файлы и каталоги, которые нужно скопировать собираются в список
source = ['/Users/yaroslav_skripnik/notes']

#2. Резервные копии должны храниться в основном каталоге резерва

target_dir = '/Users/yaroslav_skripnik/backup'

#3. Файлы помещаются в zip-архив
#4. Именем для zip-архива служит текущая дата и время
target = target_dir + os.sep + time.strftime('%Y%m%d%H%M%S') + '.zip'

#5. Используем команду "zip" для помещения файлов в zip-архив
zip_command = "zip-qr{0}{1}".format(target,''.join(source))

print('zip command is', zip_command)
#запускаем создание резервной копии
if os.system(zip_command) == 0:
    print('SUCCES', target)
else:
    print("NOPE")
    


import os
import time

this_dir = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
file = os.path.join(this_dir, 'file_name')

target_dir = '\\Users\\yaroslav_skripnik\\backup'

target = target_dir + os.sep + time.strftime('%Y%m%d%H%M%S') + '.zip'

zip_command = "zip-qr{0}{1}".format(target, '\\Users\\yaroslav_skripnik\\Desktop')
print('что с тобой не так!!!\n', zip_command )
if os.system(zip_command) == 0:
    print('SUCCES', target)
else:
    print('NOPE\n', zip_command)
```

Comment: Could you provide the comments in English? SO is an English only site, and it would help people understand your code much more quickly.

Answer (score 0):

- There was a spacing issue with the zip_command
- Maybe the error was because `target_dir` does not exist in the file system. So I've added an [`os.makedirs`](https://docs.python.org/library/os.html#os.makedirs) which will create the directory is it does not exist already.

```py
import os
import time

source = ['/Users/yaroslav_skripnik/notes']

target_dir = '/Users/yaroslav_skripnik/backup'

os.makedirs(target_dir, exist_ok = True)

target = target_dir + os.sep + time.strftime('%Y%m%d%H%M%S') + '.zip'

zip_command = "zip -qr {0} {1}".format(target, ' '.join(source))

if os.system(zip_command) == 0:
    print("SUCCESS", target)
else:
    print("NOPE")
```